# how to display csv file from sql database to php webpage?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, opencsv

I am developing one php website with sql server 2008.

I have a feature to attach a document and display it.

I am storing the attached document in database.
for that my table field is "image".

This is working fine with all document. but its not working with .csv files.

Can anyone help me to display csv file on my php webpage ?

My code to display document in php is as follows :

```
 $filename=$doc["DocumentName"];
    $file= $doc["data"];
    if($doc["OLEClassName"]=="image")
    {
     $im = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($file));
        if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($file)); 
        imagejpeg($im);
        //imagedestroy($im);
        }
        else {
            echo 'An error occurred.';
        }
    }
    else if($doc["OLEClassName"]=="txt")
    {
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        echo base64_decode($file);
    }
    else if($doc["OLEClassName"]=="P" || $doc["OLEClassName"]=="pdf")
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        echo base64_decode($file);
    }
    else if($doc["OLEClassName"]=="docx")
    {
        header('Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        echo base64_decode($file);
    }
    else if($doc["OLEClassName"]=="xlsx")
    {
        header('Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        echo base64_decode($file);
    }
    else if($doc["OLEClassName"]=="csv")
    {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        echo base64_decode($file);
    }
```

This code is working fine with other documents but not working with csv files.

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Follow @Cumbo comment and check that if input contains character from outside the base64 alphabet or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `header('Content-Type: application/csv');` instead.

**Edit** It might also help to have a Content-Disposition in the header as well.

Here's an example that I have used in the past

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= ' . basename($str_filename));
```

Comment: Follow @Cumbo comment and check that if input contains character from outside the base64 alphabet or not.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, store it in one of the folder and save the path of it in String type field.